# ThreadLocal not working in Controller after setting it on doFilterInternal method of OncePerRequestFilter abstract

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multithreading, java-17

I set the InheritableThreadLocal only in Filter class but it returns null value when I access it inside controller

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException {
        try {
            if (isAuthorized(request, response)) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                respondUnauthorized(response);
//              UserContextHolder.clearUserContext();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            respondUnauthorized(response);
//          UserContextHolder.clearUserContext();
        }
//        finally {
//            UserContextHolder.clearUserContext();
//        }
    }
```

```
private boolean isAuthorized(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String accessToken = request.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER);
        if (accessToken == null) {
            return false;
        }

        DecodedJWT jwt = decodedToken(accessToken);
        String realm = extractRealm(jwt);
        if (realm == null) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            String keyId = jwt.getHeaderClaim(KEY_CLAIM).asString();
            populateUserContext(accessToken, realm);
            return validateToken(accessToken, getPublicKey(realm, keyId), realm);
        } catch (TokenExpiredException e) {
            AccessAndRefreshToken accessAndRefreshToken = refreshToken(accessToken, jwt, realm);
            response.setHeader(AUTH_HEADER, accessAndRefreshToken.accessToken());
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

[Setting the InheritableThreadLocal in one of its method (populateUserContext)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFnvK.png)

```
private void populateUserContext(String token, String realm) {
        DecodedJWT decodedToken = JWT.decode(token);
        Claim userId = decodedToken.getClaim("s");
        Claim userEmail = decodedToken.getClaim("username");
        Claim userGroups = decodedToken.getClaim("Groups");
        TokenDataDto userContext = new TokenDataDto();
        userContext.setUserLogin(userEmail.asString());
        userContext.setIdpUserId(userId.asString());
        userContext.setRealm(realm);
        userContext.setUserRoles(userGroups.asList(String.class));
        userContext.setAccessToken(token);
        UserContextHolder.setUserContext(userContext);
    }
```

[populateUserContext sets the InheritableThreadLocal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSwrR.png)

[InheritableThreadLocal variable inside method of filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsUai.png)

[I also delete the clearing of InheritableThreadLocal just to test that no class is clearing it programatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjdzA.png)

I get InheritableThreadLocal in the controller but value is null.
[InheritableThreadLocal in controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YeA0.png)

```
 public ResponseEntity<Void> disable(String userId, String xsessionToken) {
        if (permService.hasAdminRole(userContext.getIdpUserId())) {
            myUserService.disableAdminUser(userId);
```

[userContext inside filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIixs.png)
[Another log of filter above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDQPc.png)